# Adding a reply counter to a reddit bot

Tags: python, praw

I have a bot that responds to comments/replies that include certain key words. To prevent people from spamming the bot, i want to add a counter so that when the counter reaches a certain number, for example 5 times for every comment thread, i want the bot to stop responding in that thread. The way i want to do this is to add a counter and increase it by 1 for every time the bot responds to a single comment thread. Here is the code:

```
import praw
import config
import os

Black_list = []
Counter = 0

def bot_giris():
    r = praw.Reddit(username = config.username,
                password = config.password,
                client_id = config.client_id,
                client_secret = config.client_secret,
                user_agent = "Reddit bot")


    return r

def bot_calis(r, comments_replied_to):
    subreddit = r.subreddit('gereksiz')
    for comment in subreddit.comments(limit=10):
        if 'Something' in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
            print ("String found: " + comment.id)
            print(20*"-")
            print ("Comment author: ", comment.author)
            print(20*"-")
            comment.reply("Something else")
            Counter += 1
            print ("Responded: " + comment.id)
            print(20*"-")

            comments_replied_to.append(comment.id)

            with open ("comments_replied_to.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(comment.id + "\n")


    time.sleep(10)

def get_saved_comments():
    if not os.path.isfile("comments_replied_to.txt"):
        comments_replied_to = []
    else:
        with open("comments_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
            comments_replied_to = f.read()
            comments_replied_to = list(comments_replied_to)
            comments_replied_to = list(filter(None, comments_replied_to))

    return comments_replied_to

r = bot_giris()
comments_replied_to = get_saved_comments()


while True:
    bot_calis(r, comments_replied_to)
```

Comment: Can you provide more specific info on what you are not able to achieve?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Right now if someone responds to the bot with "Something", the bot will automatically respond with "Something else". The problem here is people can make the bot spam by responding to the bot with "Something" over and over again. I want to make it so they can only do it for 5 times max. I'm sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to initialize your `counter` variable by writing `counter = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a cool down time, for example, ignore all replies for 5 minutes, then, begin responding again.  Something like this:

```
last = time.time()

def bot_calis(r, comments_replied_to):
  subreddit = r.subreddit('gereksiz')
  for comment in subreddit.comments(limit=10):
    if 'Something' in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
      ...
      if Counter >= 5:
        # 5 minute cool down
        # or, just return here
        if time.time() - last > 5 * 60 * 1000:
          Counter = 0
        else:
          return
      last = time.time()
      Counter += 1
      comment.reply("Something else")
      ...
```